# How to 'order' your callbacks without using a blocking structure

Tags: node.js, callback

I'm new to node.js and Stack Overflow and I'm having a little trouble: I want to read two files and do something with them in a specific order. Problem being that I don't know which one will finish being read first so I don't know how to make sure they will trigger in the right order.

To give an example let's say that I want to read two files and write them in the response:

```
fs.readFile('./file1',(err,data) => {
    res.write(data);
})
fs.readFile('./file2',(err,data) => {
    res.write(data);
})
```

How could I make sure the first file will be written before the second even if the second file is smaller than the first one?

I could do that:

```
fs.readFile('./file1',(err,data) => {
    res.write(data);
    fs.readFile('./file2',(err,data) => {
        res.write(data);
    })
})
```

But it would act like a blocking structure: the second one couldn't start being read before the end of the first one and that's not the point of Node.js... Am I right?

P.S. Sorry if the question is dumb or for my poor English

Comment: It doesn't act like blocking structure because it's asynchronous and non-blocking. *that's not the point of Node.js* - the point is to provide the implementation that suits your needs. If you need to write files in series then what you listed is the right way to do this. If you want to write them in parallel then you don't need to nest readFile.

Comment: You can use `promise` and/or `async/await`. Search on those topics and you'll get tons of good answers. MDN docs is a good place to start

Comment: There are only 2 ways I think you would want to do it with node. Either its in series meaning second one starts only after first one finishes, or let both of them happen in parallel. In both cases, you have written the code what is needed. Whats bothering you ?

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar Thank you this seems to be what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the reason (out of several) `Promise` and `async/await` exists is to solve exactly this kind of issue.

You can create a wrapper to return `Promise`:

```
function readSomething(filePath) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(filePath, (err, data) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(data);
    });
}
```

Then you can call like,

```
// called in parallel
const result1 = readSomething('./file1');
const result2 = readSomething('./file2');

result1.then((data) => {
  res.write(data) // or anything
  // to order, chaining promise
  return result2;
})
.then(data => res.write(data))
```

With `async/await` you can do (`await` is valid only inside `async function`):

```
async function handleResults() {
  res.write(await result1)
  res.write(await result2)
}
```

Note: Watch out for error (`reject` cases). They become a little tricky in this situation. (I'm you can figure it out)

In `nodejs` you can utilise the power of `EventEmitter` as well. You can also check out `reactive programming` implemented by [`rxjs` library](https://www.learnrxjs.io/) for `Observer` pattern.

Answer (score -1):

```
let file1 = fs.readFile('./file1')
let file2 = fs.readFile('./file2');
file1 = await file1;
file2 = await file2;
res.write(file1)
res.write(file2)
```

By this reading takes place in paralle, but if you know before hand that file1 is going to be comparatively big you can swap the await statements. And then you can write in whichever order you want to.