# page renders before getting all the values sorted

Tags: node.js

I think the rendering takes place before the searching of the string on the files, i have tried different methods but don't seems to get this working. any help will be appreciated. im a noob on to the nodejs. im trying to get the id of the user and query and get all the data and there after see if he is in any of the lists given and finally render the page.

```
    const j = [];
let name = '';
const filename = [];
var ext = '';

module.exports = function(app, express) {

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/cusdetails', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {

var cusid=req.body.cusid;

var insertQuerys = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE cusid=? ORDER BY rowid DESC LIMIT 1";

     connection.query(insertQuerys,[cusid],
      function(err, rows){ 
        rows.forEach( (row) => {
          name=row.fncus;

});

fs.readdir('./views/iplist', function(err, files) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    for (var index in files) {

        j.push(files[index])
    }

    j.forEach(function(value) {

var k = require('path').resolve(__dirname, '../views/iplist/',value);

fs.exists(k, function(fileok){
  if(fileok) {
        fs.readFile(k, function(err, content) {
           if (err) throw err;
            if (content.indexOf(name) > -1) {
                ext = path.extname(k);
                filename.push(path.basename(k, ext));
            }
        });
      }
      else {
        console.log(" FileNotExist ");
      }
    });
 });
}); 

            console.log(filename);
            res.render('cusdetails.ejs', {rows: rows, user:req.user , aml: filename });
});
     })
```

Comment: You can use `Promise` and/or `async/await` to achieve what you're trying to do. Like this `ordering` problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55361774/7185241

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar could you help me with the code adjustment? it would be really helpful to understand. i have been trying for hours but still couldn't get the hang of it.

Comment: which package are you using for sql query?

Comment: mysql is the one im using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create simple `Promise` wrapper and then use it inside `async/await` function to *pause* execution until `resolved`.

```
// use mysql2 package as it provides promise, less work to write promise wrappers
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

// create the connection to database
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  database: 'test'
});

// sample wrapper
function some(k) {
    // more advisable to have local variables, why do you need this to be array?
    var filename = [];
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // doing this is also not recommended check nodejs documentation **fs.exists** for more info
      fs.exists(k, function(fileok){
        if(fileok) {
          fs.readFile(k, function(err, content) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            if (content.indexOf(name) > -1) {
              ext = path.extname(k);
              filename.push(path.basename(k, ext));
              resolve(filename)
            }
          });
        }
        else {
          // reject(new Error("FileNotExist"))
          console.log(" FileNotExist ");
        }
      });
    })
  }

// note the use of async
app.post('/cusdetails', isLoggedIn, async function (req, res) {

  var cusid=req.body.cusid;

  var insertQuerys = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE cusid=? ORDER BY rowid DESC LIMIT 1";

    // using await to pause excution, waits till query is finished
    const [rows] = await connection.query(insertQuerys,[cusid])
    rows.forEach( (row) => {
      name=row.fncus;

  });

  // then you can
  var result = await some(k)
  ...
```

Note however this way you loose the advantage of `concurrent` execution, as it's kindoff blocking. If the result of one call is not used in another, you can execute in `parallel` and `await` for result to achieve sequencing like

```
const [rows] = connection.query(insertQuerys,[cusid])

var result = some(k)

console.log(await rows) // do something
console.log(await result) // do something
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is asynchronous. This means that if you have a function with a callback (i.e. your query), the callback will be called asynchronously, at an unknown time, while the other code executes.

You need to look up some tutorials how to deal with callbacks, to get a proper understanding of it. Another method is using `async/await` and/or promises.

Basically, if you take the following code:

```
console.log("this will print first");

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("this will print last");
}, 1000);

console.log("this will print second");
```

If you run the code above, the top level is executed synchronously, so, it first calls `console.log`, then it executes `setTimeout`, which is synchronous. It sets a timeout, then says "I'm ready", and the code continues to the other `console.log`. After 1 second (1000 milliseconds), the callback in the `setTimeout` function is executed, and only then that `console.log` is called. You can not make the rest of the code wait this way, you need to restructure your code or read into promises.

Comment: Hi thank you, but how do i figure out the timeout? more the files it would be hard to get the time right?

Comment: That's not the point of my answer. The timeout was an example to show you that callbacks are not called in the order you code them in. PHP is a language where each line is executed before the other, JavaScript isn't. You need to restructure your code, continue execution once a file has loaded. You can do this by putting the code in the callback of another piece of code, but that'll create [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/)